# Composition of everywhere discontinuous bijection with itself, limit, and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

> Let $\phi$ be everywhere discontinuous bijection that maps $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$.
>
> Define $\phi^n=\underbrace{\phi\circ \phi\cdots \phi}_{n\text{ times}}$ where $\circ$ is ordinary composition of functions.
>
> Define $\psi= \lim_{n \to + \infty} \phi^n$
>
> Can $\psi$ be everywhere continuous?

Some of my thoughts on this problem:

Since $\phi$ is a bijection so is $\phi^n$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$. Since limit should not destroy bijectivity I think that $\psi$ also is a bijection and if also everywhere continuous that means that it is everywhere strictly monotone so everywhere differentiable. And, I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  For instance, it's possible that $\phi^n(x)\to 0$ for all $x$.  As a sketch of how to construct such a $\phi$, build its orbits one by one by a transfinite recursion of length $\mathfrak{c}$.  In each step, you just pick a $\mathbb{Z}$-indexed sequence of new points converging to $0$ to be a new orbit.  All you have to do is arrange that every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is eventually put in an orbit and you avoid continuity at any point, which is easy (for instance, you can easily arrange that the image of every interval is dense, using just the first $\omega$ steps of the construction).

Note that $\lim\phi^n(x)=\lim\phi^n(\phi(x))$ (assuming either limit exists), so $\psi$ must satisfy $\psi(\phi(x))=\psi(x)$.  So $\psi$ can actually never be injective (assuming it is defined in the first place).

Comment: How can $\phi^n \to 0$ if $\phi^n (\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$?

Comment: Ignoring the discontinuity condition, consider the example $\phi(x)=x/2$, for instance.

Comment: Ignoring the discontinuity condition ignores the whole question.

Comment: @Clayton I am having internet connectivity problems, I do not repeat the comments, they just come in pairs. I do not know why.

Comment: @AnteP.: Ah. This has happened to me on a handful of occasions. Sorry for the confusion; I thought you were being borderline belligerent.

Comment: I don't know why you think $\phi^n\to 0$ should contradict $\phi^n(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$, but it seems unlikely that your intuition for this has anything to do with the discontinuity condition.  If you want any additional explanation you will need to explain why you think $\phi^n\to 0$ and $\phi^n(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$ are incompatible.

Comment: @EricWofsey I do not know why, I am not able now to prove that.

Comment: I gave you +1, but I am not completely sure in your argument.